# Nested select as where arguments

Tags: sql, nested, aggregate

I have the following table structure:

**bookings**

```
id
```

**tickets**

```
id  
booking_id  
price
```

**payments**

```
id  
booking_id  
amount
```

I would like to select all tickets that have been fully paid for.

Pseudo-SQL for main query:

```
SELECT * FROM tickets
  WHERE
  sum of all payment amounts with this booking_id
  >=
  sum of all ticket prices with this booking_id
```

SQL for "sum of all payment amounts with this booking_id":

```
SELECT sum(payment.amount) FROM payments WHERE payments.booking_id = XXX
```

SQL for "sum of all ticket prices with this booking_id":

```
SELECT sum(tickets.price) FROM tickets WHERE tickets.booking_id = XXX
```

**How can I integrate the second and third query into the first one to return all paid tickets?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another, joining the nested queries on those records which meet your criteria:

```
SELECT tickets.* 
FROM 
tickets 
INNER JOIN
(
    (
        SELECT tickets.booking_id, sum(tickets.price) as owed 
        FROM tickets
        GROUP BY tickets.booking_id
    ) AS a 
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT payments.booking_id, sum(payments.amount) as paid
        FROM payments
        GROUP BY payments.booking_id
    ) AS b
    ON a.booking_id = b.booking_id AND a.owed <= b.paid
)
ON tickets.booking_id = a.booking_id
```